# How do i read from a file to a double in allegro C++?

Tags: file, text, double, allegro

I am working with a project but I can't seem to read from a file to a double. Please help me.

This is my code:

```
std::ifstream loadFile1("voltagelevel.txt"); if (loadFile1) {

while (loadFile1&&loop<20)
{ 
loadFile1 >> voltagelevel[loop];
textprintf_ex(screen, font, 50, 100+(loop*10), makecol(255,0,0),-1, "%ld", voltagelevel[loop]);
loop++;
} 
loadFile1.close(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The allegro textprintf arguments are incorrect. I assume that you want a long double, in that case change it to `%Lf` or if you want just a double, `%f`

`textprintf_ex(screen, font, 50, 100+(loop*10), makecol(255,0,0),-1, "%Lf", voltagelevel[loop]);`

`textprintf_ex(screen, font, 50, 100+(loop*10), makecol(255,0,0),-1, "%f", voltagelevel[loop]);`

Also, the default font is an 8x8 size but it's not required to space it evenly.